# gravity form $_POST issue

Tags: php, wordpress, post, gravityforms

I've been wrapping my head around this issue for at least a couple days now, searched online and even broke the code down to make sure I'm not missing anything.

The Goal: I'm simply grabbing the value from the Birthdate field, calculate it, then save it to the hidden field which is called 'Age'.

The Issue: I am able to grab the value and calculate just fine. However I am unable to store/save it to that specific field, which as you will see in the code is field id= 47. Whenever I run the app, fill out the form and checked the Entries, the #47 pops up (it is not related to the id#. I ran some test like saving it into another field and it was the same). I am able to 'echo' out the var $age and it gives me exactly what I want. However when I try to save it, it gives me the aforementioned '47'.

On the line that contains '$_POST['input_47'] = $age', that is where my issue is. I know I can pass integer and strings to the $_POST, but it will not accept the $age.

Please let me know if I haven't made my request clear. Thank you very much to anyone who can provide a hint or two to get this resolved!

Here's the code that I placed on functions.php *edited

```
add_filter( 'gform_pre_submission_filter_1', 'pre_submission', 10, 4 );

function pre_submission ($form) {
                // Calculate the age based on incoming variable $fsmConvert
                $ageTime = strtotime($_POST['input_26']);
                $t = time(); // current timestamp
                $ageConvert = ($ageTime < 0) ? ( $t + ($ageTime * -1) ) : $t - $ageTime;
                $year = 60 * 60 * 24 * 365;
                $ageYears = $ageConvert / $year; // if you want exact estimate, STOP HERE
                $age = floor($ageYears); //this is calculated age

                foreach($form['fields'] as $field2) {
                    if(strpos($field2['id'], 47) === false) {
                        continue;
                        $field2['defaultValue'] = $age;
                    }
                }   

                // return $form;
                return $form;
}
```

Comment: What does `$form` look like?

Comment: Right now if I echo out the $form, only the date is showing (ex: 2012-04-25). Thanks Optimae

Comment: `strpos` does not correctly work with integers, so the `strpos($field2['id'], 47)` is buggy and needs the string `'47'`.

Comment: Good catch Deadooshka! I've changed it to string but still having issue with is saving to Entries.

Comment: 1. seems the `( $t + ($ageTime * -1) )` is the same as `$t - $ageTime` so the condition `$ageTime < 0` looks meaningless. 2. the `$field2['defaultValue'] = $age;` after the `continue;` will never be executed.

Comment: Thanks Deadooshka! How do I properly store the value into my hidden field of id = 47?

Comment: `foreach($form['fields'] as &$field2) { if(strpos($field2['id'], '47') !== false) { $field2['defaultValue'] = $age; break;}}` if you changes the `$form['fields']` then the `$field2` should be passed by ref.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I have read briefly about passing by reference and I can see why you suggested it. (I'll definitely followup and educate myself on pass by ref). My next issue is still the same. $field2['defaultValue'] = $age still does not work, however if I use $_POST['input_47'] = $age, it does. I do understand using $_POST is not the recommended way to do this. Would you be able to provide some suggestions to solve this? Thanks Deadooshka!

Comment: make `var_dump($form)`. Maybe your case is `$field2['name']`, and also the `$field2['defaultValue']` looks weird.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding your $age variable in $_POST directly, you can try to add it in $value variable.

**Note :** By default $form contains whole Gravity form inputs and $value contains all the inputs that user passed.

Let me know if I can help you further....

Comment: Did you mean I should return the $value instead of $form? How do I ensure that the $age is added to the field id of 47? Thank you for taking the time to help!

Comment: Yes, but not exactly. Actually you are using gform_pre_submission_1 filter and gform_save_field_value_1_47 hook, with 4 parameters, to modify $_POST variable.

This will not work because of many reasons :-
1) you have added 4 parameters while calling that hook but in function you have passed only 2 arguments. By this hook won't get called

2) you are trying to modify $_POST variable directly, which is wrong. You need to modify your first parameter and than return it. So the data will get changed.

Hope I am clear enough.

Let me know if you want me to help further.

Comment: Hi WildProgrammers, thanks for your feedback! I took out the other hooks and left only 'gform_pre_submission_filter'. Everything works accept saving it into the specific field I want. You mentinoed modifying the $_POST is wrong. So I'm trying to loop through the fields and have it look for that specific id. This still does not work as it isn't showing up in my Entries. Do you have any suggestions on how to correctly save my $age data to that specific field id?

Comment: Above solution must work. Surely, you must be doing something wrong. I need to check code in order to help you further...

Comment: Let me know exactly what you need.

Comment: Your site's admin details and FTP details ( ofcourse as this will take some effort, this will cost you ) You can contact me on Skype. My ID is wildprogrammers

Comment: As this is a client's website and knowing I have to get permission from a lot of people at work, I am not able to do this. Thank you for your help regardless! You have been very helpful and responsive!

Comment: You can setup the script on some other domain and allow me to work.
If cost is the issue than let me know....

Comment: I'm sure it's okay but as I mentioned, not my call. If I can't get this solved by this coming Monday then I'll run it through my peers to make sure I get the okay.

Comment: Ok. Let me know if I can help you. Also add me in skype, I will be more responsive there...